# Async tree exploration with RxJava

Tags: rx-java2

I'm trying to build an algorithm to explore a tree with RxJava.

My reason to use RxJava is that my node processing function is already using RxJava to send RPCs to other services. Note that the order in which the different branches of the tree are explored is not important.

Ideally, I would like to have something like a `QueueFlowable<Node> extends Flowable<Node>` which would expose a `push` function that `Observers` could use to add new nodes in the queue after processing them.

```java
private static main(String[] args) {
  QueueFlowable<Node> nodes = new QueueFlowable<>();

  nodes.push(/* the root */);
  nodes.concatMap(node -> process(node)).map(nodes::push));
  nodes.blockingSubscribe();
}

// Processes the node and returns a Flowable of other nodes to process.
private static Flowable<Node> process(Node node) { ... }
```

This sounds like something relatively common (as I would expect web crawlers to implement something similar) but I still don't manage to make it work.

My latest attempt was to use a `PublishProcessor` as follows:

```java
PublishProcessor<Mode> nodes = PublishProcessor.create();

nodes.concatMap(node -> process(node)).subscribe(nodes);
nodes.onNext(/* the root node */);

nodes.blockingSubscribe();
```

Of course, this never terminates as the processor does not complete.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: There is a 3rd party operator [expand](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaExtensions#flowabletransformersexpand) that lets you do iterative descent.